# How to Redirect if bad url comes on laravel?

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, laravel, laravel-4

How to redirect / handle when we add `<script>document.cookie<%2fscript>` in to url, I tried alot but didn't get any success. Like:

```
www.localhost.com/<script>document.cookie<%2fscript>.
```

Is there any way to handle it via route file or htaccess file? If there then please help me to solve that.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to do it via apache htaccess, you can use this example:

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} (\<|%3C).*script.*(\>|%3E) [NC,OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} GLOBALS(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2}) [OR]
    RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} _REQUEST(=|\[|\%[0-9A-Z]{0,2})
    RewriteRule .* index.php [F,L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this.

```
App::missing(function($exception)
{
    return Response::view('errors.missing', array(), 404);
});
```

Comment: In which file i can use this statement?

Comment: As stated in the docs http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/errors there is no specific file but you can place it in the global.php file

Comment: it showing me Not Found

The requested URL /projects<script>document.cookie</script> was not found on this server.